# Why does Samsung's implementation of Android 4 browser load 3 font copies and how to fix it?

Tags: android, css, fonts, webfonts, samsung-mobile

We use fontspring "bulletproof syntax" to load webfonts as shown here http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax

Syntax works everywhere except for Samsung implementation of Android 4 (e.g. in Samsung Galaxy S2 running Android 4.0.4).

When I load a page intercepting all traffic in the middle, I can see the following strange things happening:

1) Browser loads .woff files that Android is not supposed to be supporting at all. And for one of the fonts only woff is loaded and I see it used just fine. It's good, it's the smallest file - maybe some Samsung-specific font support

2) For two other fonts, browser loads 3 (three!) versions of the font: woff, ttf and svg. All the 3 fonts we use are declared in the identical manner yet for one font Galaxy S2 loads woff only and for the other two - several versions.

What's happening? Anybody had a similar situation? How to fix it?

P.S.
Sample font declaration:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```